# Get max value of column from database inside data flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I want to create a SSIS package to import survey data from EXCEL file to SQL Server table. The first column of the table is a `RESPONSE_ID`, which I have to increment each time I insert a new record. So, I want to get before each insert, the `MAX(RESPONSE_ID)` of column in a variable, increment this variable by one and use it for the next record. Please, how can I do this?

Note: It's not useful to make `RESPONSE_ID` as an `identity`, so it increments itself.

Thanks

Comment: you can create an IDENTITY(1,1) column in the back end SQL table - this is your best option. This column will automatically increament for each import.

Comment: The problem is, when I delete some data the ID is not going to be updated (decrease)

Comment: Why would you care if the identity skips numbers on a delete? As long as the foreign keys are kept (that is the biggest issue with reseeding), you should be fine. Also, Identity is not a great counter if that is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `DBCC CHECKIDENT` management command is used to reset identity counter. The command syntax is:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (table_name [, { NORESEED | { RESEED [, new_reseed_value ]}}])
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
```

Example:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[TestTable]', RESEED, 0);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

okay, if you are deleting rows. You might have to reseed the ID column. You do that like this:

```
DECLARE @Max INT;
SET @Max = (SELECT MAX (identity_column_name) FROM table_name);
DBCC CHECKIDENT('table_name', RESEED, @Max);
```